# Nodejs image outside htmlpath does not work

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, relative-path

I am working with on a user profile page with nodejs where the user can see his own avatar after login. The user has the posibility to upload the files to the uploads folder which is outside the regular **htmlpath**. I have the following folder structure:

- Layouts
- node_modules
- public (all static files)
- schema
- uploads (user uploaded files)

  ```
     eps
       euro-pool-1501781922012.jpg
  ```
- util
- views

These are the settings for the htmlpath in app.js:

```
app.use(require('serve-static')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

on the client side i use this relative path to the image:

```
<img src="../uploads/eps/euro-pool-1501781922012.jpg" class="img-circle profile-avatar" alt="User avatar" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

i also tried

```
 <img src="./uploads/eps/euro-pool-1501781922012.jpg" class="img-circle profile-avatar" alt="User avatar" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

but when i navigate to the page it failed to show the image and i get the folowing error back:

```
GET http://192.168.2.20:3000/uploads/eps/euro-pool-1501781922012.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it posible to acces files outside the htmlpath?
2. How can i fix this problem without moving the whole folder to the public folder?

Many thanks,

Erik

Comment: What do you mean by htmlpath? Do you mean your static public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, if you don't want to restrict access to this folder, you could set up two different directories to serve static files:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

In this case the path to the image should start from `/uploads`:

```
<img src="/uploads/eps/euro-pool-1501781922012.jpg" ...
```